# make Deposit at first ,after pay remaining amount using magento

Tags: magento, payment

i am new to magento. please clarify me i want to do below task

if cart amount greater than (grand total)500 then charge 10% deposit at first and before product delivery user has to pay remaining amount. if cart amount(grand total<=500) then user has to pay total amount.

how can i do this any extension is there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The best option for your customization is to use partial capture for orders in Magento.

To achieve such customization you need:

- Check is your payment method supports partial capture for orders.
- If so, then you can change its capture method to "Authorise", so amount on credit card will be locked. And create invoice that will match 10% of the locked amount.
- As soon as order is delivered, but your customization you need create an invoice for the rest of amount.

So events you can observe:

- sales_order_place_after to create partial invoice (don't forget to set proper capture flag) with 10% of authorized amount. In case if total is less then 500 then just create an invoice with full order amount.
- in the admin panel sales manager can create invoice himself, by creating of the invoice, or if you want to make it automatic, just observe sales_order_shipment_after_save event for automatically creation of the invoice for the rest of the order amount.

Comment: Hi Ivan, is there a way to invoice a percentage of an order total or are invoices generated using product quantities only?